# SQL Need to merge the two columns based on the hour

Tags: sql-server, merge, union

I have the following query and I need to merge the two columns Total_here and Total_there based on hour_interval. I have managed to run two queries by using a UNION but that basically creates two rows for each hour (One row for 'Total new' and one row for 'Total_done'). I am running into issues when I try to convert these two rows into two columns.

```
SELECT 
    hour_interval as hours 
FROM
    SELECT  
        DATEPART(hour, person) as hour_interval,  
        COUNT(person) AS Total_person 
    FROM 
        (SELECT
             CASE
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, x.person) > 12 
                   THEN DATEADD (MINUTE, -1 * DATEPART(minute, x.person) - 1, x.person)
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, x.person) < 4  
                   THEN DATEADD (MINUTE, 55, x.person)
                ELSE x.person 
             END AS person
         FROM 
             new_table) f2

        UNION

        SELECT  DATEPART( hour , done_person ) as hour_interval_1, COUNT(done_person) AS Total_done_person FROM 
        (
            SELECT
            case when DATEPART ( hour , x.done_person ) > 12 then DATEADD (MINUTE,-1 * DATEPART ( minute , x.done_person )-1,x.done_person)
            when DATEPART ( hour , x.done_person ) < 4  then DATEADD (MINUTE, 55,x.done_person)
            else x.done_person end as done_person
            FROM done_table
        ) f3

    group by hours
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: what about `UNION ALL`?

Comment: It's the same issue

Comment: You should use `JOIN` instead of `UNION`. Simply put, `UNION` extends vertically while `JOIN` horizontally. So, you wish to have two relevant rows to be set within the same result record so you can manipulate the data within them into your desired result. That would be a `JOIN`.

Comment: expected output would really help

Comment: added the output screenshot above

Comment: is that the **Expected** output or the actual one? More, can you add some sample data for your `new_table` and `done_table` ?